# Typeahead suggestion: get id instead of value and pass the id with the URL

Tags: php, jquery, typeahead

I have a PHP and Javascript code that I am using for my typeahead search feature and it is working fine. But if you look at the code below, I am passing the search value, how can I grab the id and pass to the form URL?

HTML

```
<form method="get" class="form-inline customers" autocomplete="off" action="/customers/<?php echo id; ?> ">       
<input class="customers" id="customers" type="text" name="customers">
<button type="submit" title="Search Customers"></button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input.customers').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
var countrycode = '<?php echo $agencyid; ?>';
    return $.get('fetch_customers.php', { query: query, cc: countrycode }, function (data) {
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    return process(data);
    });
    },
    });
    });
    </script>
```

PHP

```
$countrycode1 = $_GET['cc'];
 $sql="SELECT
       first_name,
       last_name,
       id,
       status,
       agency_id
       FROM customers
       WHERE (agency_id = '$countrycode1') AND first_name LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%' LIMIT 20";
   $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". 
   mysqli_error($conn));
   $json = array();
   while( $rowscity = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
   $json[] = $rowscity["first_name"];
   $json[] = $rowscity["id"];
    }
   $output = json_encode($json);
   echo $output;
   mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to pass id which returns from php file within your $.get request? If yes, then do you want this returned id to set in your form action like customer/returnedID ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I need to return customer/returnedID. As of now it is returning customer/First+Name

Comment: Do you means your PHP file is returning First+Name instead of id right ?

Comment: Yes it is.The PHP file is returning the First+Name. But it should return the id.

Comment: Let me test your code on my localhost. Your code seems good lemme check

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @Abdul Any luck?     :)

Comment: Wait I had a lunch break.. Just starting on it now

Comment: Hey no problem. :-)

Comment: First of all your mistake is in your query. Your query will return 20 records to you but you need to return only one id to set in your form action.

Comment: Also do this 
while( $rowscity = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
   $json[]['first_name'] = $rowscity["first_name"];
   $json[]['id'] = $rowscity["id"];
    }

Comment: And do i need to make any changes in the form action?

Comment: No you don't need to do any change in your form. Let me modify your php script and send you in answer

Comment: I think you don't need first_name for this purpose right?

Comment: You need only ID from php script to change your form action right ?

Comment: i just tried changing the script as u said. But guess its not working. Lemme check it again.

Comment: The scenario is there is a search text box, where the users fills the first name and it should be autocompleted through ajax. And when i submit the form it should return the id of the first_name.

Comment: yes i need to pass only the ID with the form action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP Script:

```
<?php

$countrycode1 = $_GET['cc'];
$sql = "SELECT
       first_name,
       last_name,
       id,
       status,
       agency_id
       FROM customers
       WHERE (agency_id = '" . $countrycode1 . "') AND first_name LIKE '%" . $_GET['query'] . "%' LIMIT 1";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:" . mysqli_error($conn));
$json = array();
while ($rowscity = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
    echo $rowscity["id"]; exit; 
}
?>
```

Your Script can be like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input.customers').typeahead({
            source: function (query, process) {
                var countrycode = '<?php echo $agencyid; ?>';
                $.get('fetch_customers.php', {query: query, cc: countrycode}, function (data) {
                    $('form').attr('action', '/customers/' + data); 
                });
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now autocomplete is not working. But when i enter the first name and submit the form its redirecting properly.

Comment: For autocomplete you can make another script separately

Comment: Otherwise you can manage in this script  as well by using a variable on which you can apply the if() condition to filter record basically the issue was with your query. Now you can apply your own logic as well

Comment: ohhh ok. Little confused, lemme check it.

Comment: It didnt work in my case, since the core autocomplete is not working. Anyways got a fair amount of idea on how to approach. Thx

Comment: You can simply write another script for autocomplete... That would be very easy for you.

Comment: Iam not that well versed with Ajax/Javascript. I am not sure if i make another script for autocomplete then how will i integrate your script and my script. Let me check or else need to need to find some other script for the same.

Comment: I need a small favour. In the JS i am getting $('#selectuser_id').val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to input and in return the value is been saved to a text box.       <input type='text' id='selectuser_id' />. Is there a way i can pick the value of the text box in php?

Comment: Yes you can pick the value in PHP by using another ajax request. Just send an ajax request and set that value in session after that you can get it on the same page as well within the php.

Comment: If you want to learn the code control by using different conditions or want to be an expert in ajax. I have started classes for beginers to help them to become zero to hero in PHP and jQuery